# TempData - "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, tempdata

I have a strange error. I'm using tempData to send a value from one controller to the other. It works perfectly fine when the program is running, I can call the function multiple times and temp data works as expected.

The problem occurs if I refresh the webpage. I receive this error:

```
 object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here's my code where I'm adding a value, id, to TempData:

```
    public IActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            TempData["ID"] = id;
        }
```

and here's my code where I use the value in TempData, in a separate controller:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string SubjectName, int CourseID)
        {
          
            //professor id
            int professorID = (int)TempData["ID"];
}
```

is there a way to save the values I store in temp data even when refreshing the page?

Any tips/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `id != null` when you do the refresh?

Comment: No, im saying the id is null on the refresh and im asking how to keep the value in id even when i do refresh the page.

Comment: i'll edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: well, then it all depends on how the frontend (web/javascript) is made...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can actually call the "keep" function so that any value you put in TempData lasts for more than one call.

In my second controller where I access the value in TempData, all I had to put in was this line of code:

```
     TempData.Keep("ID");
     int professorID = (int)TempData["ID"];
```

And the value will remain in the dictionary even when clicking refresh.